# Disable SSL certificate check Twisted Agents

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I am using Twisted (16.3) and Treq (15.1) to make async requests in Python (2.7).

I am having issues with some requests over HTTPS.

Some sites have an invalid certificate and thus when making a request to them, I get this:

```
twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error
```

I want my client to trust any server, including those without certificates or with self signed certificates.

How can I disable certificate checks on my client?

This is a question essentially identical to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357439/ssl-options-for-twisted-agents

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Update Feb 7, 2019

Here's a simple way to make a domain whitelist for `treq`

```
from treq.client import HTTPClient
from twisted.web.iweb import IPolicyForHTTPS
from twisted.web.client import BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS, Agent
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
from twisted.internet import task, defer, ssl
from zope.interface import implementer

@implementer(IPolicyForHTTPS)
class WhitelistContextFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, good_domains=None):
        """
        :param good_domains: List of domains. The URLs must be in bytes
        """
        if not good_domains:
            self.good_domains = []
        else:
            self.good_domains = good_domains

        # by default, handle requests like a browser would
        self.default_policy = BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS()

    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        # check if the hostname is in the the whitelist, otherwise return the default policy
        if hostname in self.good_domains:
            return ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=False)
        return self.default_policy.creatorForNetloc(hostname, port)

@task.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    # make a custom client, agent, and context factory
    # NOTE: WhitelistContextFactory() takes a list of BYTES
    treq = HTTPClient(Agent(reactor, contextFactory=WhitelistContextFactory([b'example.net'])))
    response = yield treq.get('https://example.net/version')
    content = yield response.content()
    print(content)
```

`WhitelistContextFactory` takes a `list` of URLs (in `bytes`) and checks if the `hostname` is in the list to disregard TLS verification. You can get fancy and use regex too. Kudos to https://github.com/twisted/treq/issues/213

## DO NOT DO THIS!

<s>I've been trying to do this too over the past few days as well. With all the effort I put into circumventing certificate verification, I could've easily just created a pair of keys and been on my merry way :D. I found [this comment](https://github.com/twisted/treq/issues/65#issuecomment-249034981) on the `treq` issues board that monkeypatches the issue:</s>

```
from twisted.internet import _sslverify
_sslverify.platformTrust = lambda : None
```

I'm sure there's a convoluted way of doing it "correctly" but it wouldn't be worth the effort in my opinion. I did a patch such that it wouldn't override `platformTrust()` and I'll try to get it merged but I wouldn't hold my breath. From the tone of some of the bug comments I've seen pertaining to trust roots, ssl, and certificates, I don't think it will get merged. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! I came across that comment as well but it did not help me. I am using agents for my requests, from `twisted.web.client import Agent`. I am guessing the code, `_sslverify.platformTrust = lambda : None` specifically overwrites platformTrust to do nothing. Do you know, is that applicable to agents? So is there something else that should get changed if agents are used?

Comment: This has been alluding me nearly a day now. I can't believe how bad Python / Twisted are at handling certificate validation for production/dev scenarios - is eveyone in python community using real certificates, or polluting their machines with their own CA's or just not testing SSL/TLS?

Comment: I totally agree! There are treq devs working on a "whitelist" feature which will allow select sites to go unverified. Hopefully it comes soon

Comment: It's good to know a whitelist feature is coming out. To be honest, at least for my project, I found it much easier to switch to python3.5 aiohttp. In my oppinion, it provides asynchronous requests in a more elegant way compared to Twisted, provides handling of SSL certificates and a much easier way to work with proxies, just to name a few things. Sure, it involves some rewriting but in the long run it's worth it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being honest :) Just FYI that tornado integrates well with twisted also. You could've used tornado's ``AsyncHTTPClient.fetch()`` and then integrated the event loop w/ twisted. ``asyncio`` integration is coming soon as well. This way you wouldn't have to rewrite too much code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **completely** ignore the check for SSL here is a workaround:

```
from twisted.internet import ssl, _sslverify
from twisted.web.iweb import IPolicyForHTTPS

@implementer(IPolicyForHTTPS)
class IgnoreHTTPS:
    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        options = ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=False)
        return _sslverify.ClientTLSOptions(hostname.decode('ascii'), options.getContext())
```